# custom CollectionViewCell in swift fatal error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I doing a swift project based on xib and i create a collection view in my view controller added its delegate and everything is fine using the default collectionViewCell

the problem is when i created the custom cell
i added the reuse identifier  right way in the xib

then in the did load of the view controller i add those lines

```
collectionViewCarType.delegate = self;
collectionViewCarType.dataSource = self;
collectionViewCarType.registerClass(MainScreenCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MainScreenCollectionViewCell");
```

and i added break point it is not crashing here

then in the:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

i added those lines:

```
var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MainScreenCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainScreenCollectionViewCell
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
cell.labelOfTime.text = "10 mins"
cell.labelOfType.text = "Mini"

return cell
```

and the app crash when it reach `cell.labelOfTime.text`

when i remove the labels 2 line it work fine coloring the cell

i also make the 2 label strong and the collection view but it crash also

i removed the xib and create it with different name and try to use it but i got same error too

i am new to swift and i don't know what i can do more

Comment: Please edit your question to include the crash error message.

Comment: post the code for the MainScreenCollectionViewCell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you created a `.xib`, but you're registering a class:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: view, bundle: nil)
collectionViewCarType.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MainScreenCollectionViewCell")
```

This means that when it loads your class, it's just initialized, it doesn't load it from the `.xib`, so your outlets are never set.

Answer (score 0):

You can do much of this in the storyBoard and maybe it will help.
First of all you can connect the delegate and dataSource via the storyBoard - just ctrl drag from the collection view so you don't need to write it yourself (but thats not the problem here).

The second thing is that you don't need to create nib file and you don't have to register the cell's class.

1. Add new class file - a custom UICollectionViewCell class - should look like this:

```swift
class customCell :UICollection {//implementation goes here}
```

2. Drag a `collectionViewCell` to your `collectionView`.

   3. In the Identity inspector in custom class section change the cell's class to the name of the class you just created.
   4. Add the identifier in the attribute inspector
   5. Add what ever you want to the cell (image, labels etc) and connect them to the class you created.

It will make it much easier, anyway here are some references that may help.

http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/custom-collection-view-cell-tutorial-ios8-swift
http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1